# Extracting data from javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, testcomplete

I am pretty new to xml, I am using testcomplete with Javascript. I have nested xml i am pasting a small part below.

I would like to extract rownumber and column code when rowtype category = "ExitRow" occupation is free Marketing seat type is E .

```
<Row rowNumber="011">
                    <RowCharacteristics>
                        <RowType category="ExitRow"/>
                    </RowCharacteristics>
                    <Seats>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="A">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="B">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1A"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1B"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="C">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1A"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1B"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="D">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1A"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1B"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="E">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1A"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1B"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                        <Seat occupation="Free" columnCode="F">
                            <MarketingSeatType category="E"/>
                            <PhysicalSeatTypes>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1A"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="1B"/>
                                <PhysicalSeatType category="E"/>
                            </PhysicalSeatTypes>
                        </Seat>
                    </Seats>
                </Row>
```

I have wrote some code to open xml in test complete but not sure is this correct.

```
Doc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0");
 Doc.async = false;
 Doc.load("d:\\MyFile.xml");

Node = Doc.documentElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use XPath. You can find a lot of examples in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
function test()
{
  var Doc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0");
  Doc.async = false;
  Doc.load("d:\\MyFile.xml");

  var row = Doc.selectSingleNode('//Row[RowCharacteristics/RowType/@category="ExitRow"]');
  var rowNumber = row.getAttribute("rowNumber");
  Log.Message("Row number is " + rowNumber);

  var cCodes = row.selectNodes('Seats/Seat[@occupation="Free" and MarketingSeatType/@category="E"]/@columnCode');
  for (var i = 0; i < cCodes.length; i++)
    Log.Message("Column code is " + cCodes.item(i).value);
}
```

Comment: Thats awsome Thanks I was able to extract the row and the column using the above code.                                          Actually I have more than one exit row when 1st exit row is filled the above program returned  the row number and no column name. :( I might have check all the exit rows, how do i do that and one more thing, I will be repeating the procedure to find free seets for multiple passenger is there any way once I used the seat I can change the occupation = blocked so that next time  its not selected again.

Comment: working          var numberofExitRow = Doc.selectNodes('//Row[RowCharacteristics/RowType/@category="ExitRow"]')
        
        for(j=0; j< numberofExitRow.length; j++){
           
          var  row = numberofExitRow.item(j)
          var rowNumber = row.getAttribute("rowNumber");
          BuiltIn.ShowMessage("Row number is " + rowNumber);

  var cCodes = row.selectNodes('Seats/Seat[@occupation="Free" and MarketingSeatType/@category="E"]/@columnCode');
  for (var i = 0; i < cCodes.length; i++)
    BuiltIn.ShowMessage("Column code is " + cCodes.item(i).value);
}

Comment: Still need to figure out next part how do I changed the seat to occupied after using :)

Comment: You need to get the node you need to change and then assign a new value to it. It seems that you need some basic knowledge on the XML processing. You can find a tutorial along with a lots of samples here: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/